# Select distinct nodes with Gremlin?

Tags: gremlin

If there are multiple edges connecting the same pair of nodes, `both` will come back with duplicated nodes:

```
gremlin> v2 = g.addVertex(null,['x':5,'y':7])
==>v[360004]
gremlin> v3 = g.addVertex(null, ['x':2,'y':3])
==>v[360008]
gremlin> g.addEdge(v2,v3,'test')
==>e[6IeZ-1vEw-2F0LaTPQQu][360004-test->360008]
gremlin> g.addEdge(v2,v3,'test 2')
==>e[6If7-1vEw-2F0LaTPQQC][360004-test 2->360008]
gremlin> v2.both.map
==>{y=3, x=2}
==>{y=3, x=2}
```

How can ensure that I get back a distinct list of nodes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`dedup` makes this easy and is explained in the [Gremlin docs](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#dedup-step).  For the example above:

```
gremlin> v2.both.dedup.map
==>{y=3, x=2}
```